# Interview invite after having started a new job, requesting an updated resume

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, resume, new-job

About three months ago I applied for a job with Company A, which I was really interested to work for. They did not contact me, and in the meanwhile I got an offer from Company B. I accepted it and started my job  and have been there for a month. Today, Company A contacted me to invite me for an interview, but they also asked me for an updated version of my resume.

I understand that it is not professional to leave a job after one month, so I am not sure if it looks OK to mention my new commitment in the updated resume.

Should update my resume and inform them about my current job or not?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere The question was about whether I should update my resume and inform them about my current job or not and I accepted Kai's comment as an answer.

Comment: Personally, I would tell them I am no longer available and not send them anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would put the current position on there.  You may need to inform the company at some point in the interview process that you are already employed, and if that happens, it'd look weird not to have it on the resume.

I wouldn't worry about it looking badly because:

1. They went three months without contacting you, it was perfectly reasonable to assume they wouldn't be contacting you, and to get a different job in that time.
2. After a delay like that, contacting you is more similar to cold-calling you.  That they're asking for an up-to-date resume is an indication that they recognize this.
3. If they're turned off by the fact that you got another position, you don't really lose anything.  You weren't actively job seeking at this point anyways.  But hiding the fact you currently have a position could possibly cause difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should tell Company A sorry, but you already accepted a job with someone else. Withdraw from the application process with Company A. Accepting Company B's offer and then ditching them after a month is unprofessional and unethical, and will damage your reputation. You can, however, tell Company A that you'd love to work with them in the future. Then in a year or so, you can apply to another posting and also email them to say you're you couldn't take the last job but you're still really interested in joining their company so you'd love to be considered for this position, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You want us to advise what?

1. You barely started on your new job and you are still going though the adjustment process.
2. All A is doing is inviting you for an interview with, of course, no commitment to hire you. At this, you are far, far away from getting an offer from A. They are interested in interviewing you? They are most likely saying the same thing to at least three other candidates. And you have no way of knowing if they are serious about hiring and what their expected date of hiring is.

From your post, you are assuming that you're going to get an offer from A on a silver platter - that's a big assumption. I guess you want that offer from A so bad that you are acting as if you already got it. The power of auto suggestion, I guess.

What is there that you want us to advise you on? All you have is that job from B - that's it, you don't have anything else.

Comment: You are probably right about me being so desperate to get the offer form A as there is with no commitment from A and thatI barely started my on my new job. My question is about updated resume and if I need to mentioned my new job. If this was not that awkward I wouldn't mention it as a question in this forum. After all we are asking questions when we are not 100% sure.

Comment: @Hamed  - Putting your new job on your resume at this point in time is kind of useless: 1. You just started, so you have NO content for your job description; 2. If you get dismissed in the next two weeks, then you have to explain why and how you got yourself dismissed and that new job entry in your resume is no longer valid; 3.  Putting that new entry is extra work. It's tough enough to come up with a new entry when you've got good content to put in. But if you have no content to put in, filling in that entry is going to be significantly more challenging (cont)

Comment: @Hamed - And the interviewers will be going over your resume at interview time and asking you about your new job and why you'd want to leave so soon. Or they might not ask anything and just toss your resume  -  Don't wake up the beast.