# Job interviews while working new job

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer, new-job, job-change

I accepted a new job and been working here for the past 3 weeks. Before I accepted this job I had an interview for a company for the first round about a month ago and now they called me back for the final round. My question is do I bring up this new job during the interview or just go along as I am still unemployed like in the first round?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How much of a difference does being employed vs. not make in the eyes of potential employers when looking for a new postion?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/46362/how-much-of-a-difference-does-being-employed-vs-not-make-in-the-eyes-of-potenti)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I am looking to switch. My current job does not pay as well. I just needed to continue paying my mortgage. And I feel like there is slow growth here.

Comment: Related / duplicates: [Interview invite after having started a new job, requesting an updated resume](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/81872), [Quitting a job very early; how to justify it for next interview?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/70811), [How to manage re-engaging a job search after only 1 month at new job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/23017)

Answer (score 6):

> do I bring up this new job during the interview or just go along as I
>   am still unemployed like in the first round?

Don't bring up the fact that you just accepted a new job and plan to cut out as soon as you find something better. That's not something most employers would like to hear as they will wonder if you would do the same to them.

Just remain quiet and hope it doesn't come up, so that you don't have to lie about it.

Comment: However, if it **DOES** come up, **DON'T LIE.**

Answer (score 2):

> My question is do I bring up this new job during the interview or just go along as I am still unemployed like in the first round?

If you bring this up during the interview just like that will likely harm your chances.

However, if you already have a job, and don't plan on changing, *I don't see the point on pursuing this other opportunity any further*. You will only be wasting your and their time.

If that is so, it's better if you politely decline the offer, and thank them for their consideration.

If you are considering switching, I must say that accepting a job and leaving 3 weeks after is something that will surely not be taken gladly by your current employer. Or at least not something I would include on my resume.

**Edit per clarifications**:

If you are looking for a job-switch and are under-paid then surely go to the interview. However, don't just say *"hey, your offer sounds nice, but I'm currently employed"*, as that will not have a positive impact.

Just, proceed with the interview like you would do in any interview, and ***if*** they ask you if you are currently employed you should *stick to the truth* and say yes. No point in denying it, as it could be verified. Also, being employed is usually better when job-hunting (compared to being unemployed). Also, disclosing this may be necessary for you to negotiate your possible starting date given the current notice period you had.

Answer (score -1):

As you have already accepted an offer and started working there, it would be best to be **straight with them** and tell them what has happened if asked. To be totally honest I don't believe it will end in your favour however that is something you should of considered before accepting your previous job.

The new employer is likely to view this as indecisive and will be considering if you will simply hop to a new job if they give you this one.

If you lie, I think it would be reasonable to assume that it could come up at some point or they could ask you about it.

You will also have to consider any contractual notice period you may now have. If you still state you are unemployed they will assume that you can **work right away**.

On the other hand, if they don't bring it up, you don't need to tell them and it may not end up being an issue.

Comment: question isn't about telling the current employer...